# Sort list in two differents ways

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist, compare

I have a list of objects that I want to sort by date, with a condition. My aim is to get a list with ascending end_date if end_date is greater or equal than today then a list ordered by descending start_date for objets with end_date in past.

I have a model like that :

```
public class Trip implements Serializable, Comparable<Trip> {
    public int id;
    public Calendar date_begin, date_end;
}
```

and I tried that, but it doesn't work or it's too slow.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Trip trip) {
    if (date_end.getTimeInMillis() < Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() &&
        trip.date_end.getTimeInMillis() < Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()) {
        return comparePast(trip);
    } else if (date_end.getTimeInMillis() > Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() &&
            trip.date_end.getTimeInMillis() > Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()) {
        return compareCurrent(trip);
    } else {
        return date_end.compareTo(trip.date_end);
    }
}
```

Is there an easyest or fastest way?

Comment: Same thing you can achieve by using Collections.sort() method.

Comment: No .sort() method doesn't take into account my conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is making this code so slow is the many calls to `Calendar.getInstance()`, creating Calendar objects. The code would already be a lot faster if you called this once per compare.

However, it doesn't make much sense to keep creating these in a single sort run. You can either set a static Calendar reference that the sort can use, or use `System.currentTimeMillis` to get the current time.

Comment: Thanks for this usefull answer, I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

Based on [wvdz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2947592/wvdz) answer, I finally use this method to compare:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Trip trip) {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (trip.date_end.getTimeInMillis() > now && date_end.getTimeInMillis() > now) {
        return date_begin.compareTo(trip.date_begin);
    }
    return trip.date_end.compareTo(date_end);
}
```

And it works!